# Silverlight XNA Width and Height

Tags: xna, viewport

Despite the fact that I am doing the following in the Contstructor:

`SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 480;
SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;`

The `Viewport.Width` is coming out to be 480 and the `Viewport.Height` is coming out to be 800 which is the opposite of what I want.

I have set the Orientation to Landscape in XAML.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The class `SharedGraphicsDeviceManager` contains a method called `ApplyChanges()` to submit your changes.
See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.sharedgraphicsdevicemanager.applychanges.aspx) documentation.

Comment: The phone has become landscape, but, the Viewport.Width is still 480

Comment: What about operating on the `Viewport` as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.viewport.aspx)?